# How to exclude "Project not selected to build for this solution configuration" message from displaying in output window in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have several "test" projects in a visual studio solution that i have excluded from building when i rebuild the solution. However when i rebuild the solution i still see those projects in the output window with the message:

"Skipped Rebuild All: Project: PROJECTNAME, Configuration: [debug|release] CPU Project not selected to build for this solution configuration"

I understand this message but, it would be nice to not have to see it everytime i rebuild my solution. Is there any way to exclude that message from displaying in the output window when i rebuild my solution?

Comment: I think you would have to write a Visual Studio Extension to do this.  A quick search doesn't show any existing extensions that would do it.

Answer (score 10):

To solve this problem, you needs to select [build] in project configuration.

[image: Open build configuration panel]

[image: Select build option]

!!!This is would not work Until you re-launch visual studio, even you press Ctrl+s!!!
When you try to close visual studio, it will prompt you if you want to save *.sln before exit.
Save it! You should be fine now.

Comment: A little late to the party, but ctrl+shift+s (Save All) will save the .sln without having to close Visual Studio.